# Ignore cases for certain match in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

#### Question 1

I want to match pattern `dc_abc` and replace with `dc_ABC`, but if the pattern is `.dc_abc` or `"dc_abc"`, it should remain the same.

Input file:

```
.dc_abc (dc_abc);
.dc_abc({dc_abc});
dc_abc("dc_abc");
```

Output_file:

```
.dc_abc (dc_ABC);
.dc_abc({dc_ABC});
dc_ABC("dc_abc");
```

---

#### Question 2

Is there any way in Perl that I can create two arrays like:

```
@match_pattern =(!dc_abc , dc_abc: ,dc_abc );
@ignore_pattern = (.dc_abc, {dc_abc});
```

- If pattern belongs to `@match_pattern`, replace it with `dc_ABC`.
- If pattern belongs to `@ignore pattern`, don't do anything.

Input file:

```
.dc_abc(dc_abc, {dc_abc});
!dc_abc(!dc_abc);
dc_abc: (dc_abc:);
```

Output file:

```
.dc_abc(dc_ABC , {dc_abc});
!dc_abc(dc_ABC);
dc_ABC (dc_ABC);
```

Comment: I assume you already have some code to show?

Comment: I don't think the two questions is a problem since they do appear to be related, but we do need sample code, or at least some sample output.  Please play around with the code block when you're editing your question to help display your question neater and in a way that is easier to understand.

Comment: For Q1, you probably need (negative) look-ahead and look-behind (see [perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#EXTENDED-CONSTRUCTS)).  For Q2, you need to clarify whether any of the non-alphanumeric characters are metacharacters, and you also need to clarify what should happen if a string matches both an entry in `@match_pattern` and `@ignore_pattern`.  For example, the string `{dc_abc}` matches the first match and also the second ignore; should it be matched or ignored, and how is the program to know which?

Comment: I just edited it again...sorry for lack of explanation..

Comment: Oh drat! I'd reformatted your question so it was more legible, and now you've gone and changed it. Please go and re-edit. Learn how to use the 'code indentation' tool in the editor; it looks like `{}`. You select the data to be indented, and then click on that icon. It means you don't have to leave blank lines all over the place. Since you've changed the example data, I can't just rollback your handiwork, so I'm going to request that you look at what there was (click on the 'edited' time beside your name to see the revision history) in my revision (for example, the program is Perl) and redo.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am sorry to put you in trouble... I do have old revision. But I can not add it now because. this one is little clean.  However I can send you older revision in your email, if you want.

Comment: Not to worry — it was an accident of timing; just the way it goes.  I've redone it, but please do learn the basics of formatting.

Comment: You can click the text where it says "edited"; it's a link to a page where you see all the revisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match assertions. You can tell the regular expression that the part you want to match can't follow a literal dot or quote. The `(?<! )` part is the negative lookbehind. Inside that, I have the pattern `[."]`, which is a character class with the characters that can't precede the rest of the pattern:

```
use v5.10;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    s/(?<![\."])dc_abc/dc_ABC/g;
    say;
    }


__END__
.dc_abc (dc_abc);
.dc_abc({dc_abc});
dc_abc("dc_abc");
```

This gives:

```
.dc_abc (dc_ABC);
.dc_abc({dc_ABC});
dc_ABC("dc_abc");
```

The lookarounds don't match any characters, and the negative lookbehinds in Perl must be fixed width (so, no quantifiers).

For question 2, Perl has all the tools you need to do it and leaves it up to you to finish up the logic. I don't particularly feel like thinking about it this late at night though. Maybe I'll think of something later. There are various brute force ways to deal with it, but there's probably something clever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... for 2nd answer I think we can add all ignore thing in NEGATIVE look behind....it is one kind of @ignore_array... I guess